# XPath test to identify node type

Tags: xpath, types

I don't understand why this test

```
count(.|../@*)=count(../@*)
```

( from [Dave Pawson's Home page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodetest.html#d7653e255) )

identify an attribute node :(

could someone give me a detailled explanation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things to understand:

1. `.` refers to the current node (aka "context node")
2. an attribute node has a parent (the element it belongs to)
3. an XPath union operation (with `|`) never duplicates nodes, i.e. `(.|.)` results in *one* node, not two
4. there is the `self::` axis you could use in theory (e.g. `self::*` works to find out if a node is an element), but `self::@*` does not work, so we must use something different

Knowing that, you can say:

- `../@*` fetches all attributes of the current node's parent (all "sibling attributes", if you will)
- `(.|../@*)` unions the current node with them – if the current node is an attribute, the overall count does not change (as per #3 above)
- therefore, if `count(.|../@*)` equals `count(../@*)`, the current node **must be an attribute node**.

Comment: I would say "if the current node is an attribute" _and_ is among all the fetched attributes, right?

Comment: @empo: How could it *not* be among them? -- @Patrick: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, in XSLT 2.0 you can do

```
<xsl:if test="self::attribute()">...</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this works

```
count(      # Count the nodes in this set
.|../@*)    # include self and all attributes of the parent
            # this counts all of the distinct nodes returned by the expression
            # if the current node is an attribute, then it returns the count of all the
            # attributes on the parent element because it does not count the current 
            # node twice. If it is another type of node it will return 1 because only
            # elements have attribute children

=count(     # count all the nodes in this set
../@*)      # include all attribute nodes of the parent. If the current node is not an
            # attribute node this returns 0 because the parent can't have attribute
            # children
```